# numpy fit coefficients to linear combination of polynomials

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra, polynomials

I have data that I want to fit with polynomials. I have 200,000 data points, so I want an efficient algorithm. I want to use the `numpy.polynomial` package so that I can try different families and degrees of polynomials. Is there some way I can formulate this as a system of equations like Ax=b? Is there a better way to solve this than with scipy.minimize?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize as mini

x1 = np.random.random(2000)
x2 = np.random.random(2000)
y = 20 * np.sin(x1) + x2 - np.sin (30 * x1 - x2 / 10)
def fitness(x, degree=5):

    poly1 = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x1, x[:degree])
    poly2 = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x2, x[degree:])
    return np.sum((y - (poly1 + poly2)) ** 2 )

# It seems like I should be able to solve this as a system of equations
# x = np.linalg.solve(np.concatenate([x1, x2]), y)

# minimize the sum of the squared residuals to find the optimal polynomial coefficients
x = mini(fitness, np.ones(10))
print fitness(x.x)
```

Comment: Your problem is an example of a linear least squares problem. ("Linear" meaning linear in the free parameters.) The singular value decomposition is a standard method for solving such problems. A web search for these terms should turn up a lot of hits. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right. You can solve this as a system of equations of the form *Ax = b*.

However:

- The system is overdefined and you want to get the least-squares solution, so you need to use `np.linalg.lstsq` instead of `np.linalg.solve`.
- <s>You can't use `polyval` because you need to separate the coefficients and powers of the independent variable.</s>

This is how to construct the system of equations and solve it:

```
A = np.stack([x1**0, x1**1, x1**2, x1**3, x1**4, x2**0, x2**1, x2**2, x2**3, x2**4]).T             
xx = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]
print(fitness(xx))  # test the result with original fitness function
```

Of course you can generalize over the degree:

```
A = np.stack([x1**p for p in range(degree)] + [x2**p for p in range(degree)]).T
```

With the example data, the least squares solution runs much faster than the `minimize` solution (800µs vs 35ms on my laptop). However, `A` can become quite large, so if memory is an issue `minimize` might still be an option.

**Update:**

Without any knowledge about the internals of the polynomial function things become tricky, but it *is* possible to separate terms and coefficients. Here is a somewhat ugly way to construct the system matrix `A` from a function like `polyval`:

```
def construct_A(valfunc, degree):
    columns1 = []
    columns2 = []
    for p in range(degree):
        c = np.zeros(degree)
        c[p] = 1
        columns1.append(valfunc(x1, c))
        columns2.append(valfunc(x2, c))
    return np.stack(columns1 + columns2).T

A = construct_A(np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval, 5)           
xx = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]
print(fitness(xx))  # test the result with original fitness function
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad my intuition is right. I'm pretty sure this doesn't answer my question. I used `np.polynomial.polynomial` because it is a familiar example. But, I actually want to use more complicated families of polynomials. Fore example, what if I want to use the hermite_e polynomials?

Comment: I'm pretty sure It *does* answer the question. The answer was *not possible*, which may not be what you hoped for - but it's still a valid answer. Anyway, you are lucky because it turns out it is possible after all  :) See updated answer. (Simply pass `hermite_e.hermeval` to the function instead of `polyval` and you are good to go.)